# Выделение слов запятыми

Tags: пунктуация

Возможно ли Вам задать несколько вопросов? Слово Вам выделяется запятыми или нет?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: Можно ли Вам задать несколько вопросов?

Местоимение "Вам" не является обращением и не выделяется запятыми.

Форма "возможно ли Вам" применялась раньше со значение "можете ли вы", например: Вы обсудите прежде всего вопрос материальный, возможно ли Вам ассигновать для этого значительную сумму [М. М. Пришвин. Дневники (1928)].

Answer (score 1):

Не выделяется, конечно. Вы - не обращение, обращение не может отвечать но вопрос "кому". И вообще, местоимения не бывают обращениями (исключения единичны, в детской речи).

А обычный член предложения, в данном случае - дополнение, нет никаких причин обособлять.